# Customize pytorch model export to ONNX

Tags: pytorch, export, customization, onnx, mask-rcnn

I am trying to export pretrained Mask R-CNN model to ONNX format. Since this model in basic configuration has following structure (here I added `batch_size` as dynamic axes):

[image]

I want to customize my model and add `batch_size` to output (it means I need to add new dim to each of the outputs).

I wrote following code to make it possible:

```
class MaskRCNNModel(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MaskRCNNModel, self).__init__()
    self.model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights='DEFAULT')
    in_features = self.model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    self.model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes=7)
    self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load("saved_dict.torch"))

  def forward(self, input):
    outputs = self.model.forward(input)
    boxes = []
    labels = []
    scores = []
    masks = []
    for result in outputs:
        box, label, score, mask = result.values()
        boxes.append(box)
        labels.append(label)
        scores.append(score)
        masks.append(mask)
    
    return boxes, labels, scores, masks

maskrcnn_model = MaskRCNNModel()
maskrcnn_model.eval()
maskrcnn_model.to(device)

x = torch.rand(1, 3, 512, 512)
x = x.to(device)

maskrcnn_model(x)

torch.onnx.export(maskrcnn_model,
                  x,
                  "base_model_100_epochs.onnx",
                  opset_version=11,
                  input_names=["input"],
                  output_names=["boxes", "labels", "scores", "masks"])
```

but the code above doesn't change any export parameters. The structure of output stays the same:

[image]

What should I do to customize `forward` method to be able to add `batch_size` into ONNX model output?

Comment: If you're planning to deploy anything, I recommend staying far away from anything `torchvision` and looking into `caffe` or `tensorflow` alternatives. It is a great module but the Mask R-CNN implementation was not designed with `onnx` in mind, and performs extremely poorly when exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Avoid doing this

As per my original comment, I would discourage deploying most `torchvision` models with ONNX. It is all around a great module, just that it was not originally written with the intention to go well with static graphs.

If throughput is a consideration, this implementation Mask R-CNN is not the way to go. With earlier ONNX opsets, I've had this model spend most of its execution time for h2d/d2h operations when falling back to CPU. I recommend checking [YOLOv8 by ultralytics](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics) for a newer take on instance segmentation, or some of the many static implementations found on github.

###### Torchvision Mask R-CNN outputs

The model is designed with user-friendliness in mind, so for each image in the input batch it outputs a dictionary of tensors with accepted and post-processed results. For example if you have two images with ten detected objects in the first image and three in the second, the output would be

```py
batch = torch.randn((2, 3, 256, 256)) # Input two images
output = mask_rcnn(batch) # run model
results1, results2 = output # One dictionary per batch
for key, value in results1:
    print(key, value.shape)
>>> boxes [10, 4]
>>> labels [10]
>>> scores [10]
>>> masks [10, 1, 256, 256]
for key, value in results2:
    print(key, value.shape)
>>> boxes [3, 4]
>>> labels [3]
>>> scores [3]
>>> masks [3, 1, 256, 256]
```

###### Why your approach does not work

Is because ONNX does not understand `python` types. During `torch.onnx.export`, lists, dictionaries, tuples, etc. have no special meaning, and their entries are saved either as tensors or as constants. So the only thing your custom forward pass does is changes the order of the outputs, e.g. with the previous example outputs transform from

```py
>>> boxes1 [10, 4]
>>> labels1 [10]
>>> scores1 [10]
>>> masks1 [10, 1, 256, 256]
>>> boxes2 [3, 4]
>>> labels2 [3]
>>> scores2 [3]
>>> masks2 [3, 1, 256, 256]
```

to

```py
>>> boxes1 [10, 4]
>>> boxes2 [3, 4]
>>> labels1 [10]
>>> labels2 [3]
>>> scores1 [10]
>>> scores2 [3]
>>> masks1 [10, 1, 256, 256]
>>> masks2 [3, 1, 256, 256]
```

[Torch ONNX documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html#avoiding-pitfalls) is worth reading as to how `python` and `torch` types are interpreted during export.

###### Goal

Is to have the model output batched results. E.g. you want the model to output tensors

```py
boxes [batch_size, num_detections, 4]
labels [batch_size, num_detections]
scores [batch_size, num_detections]
masks [batch_size, num_detections, 1, 256, 256]
```

We immediately see that this is impossible without applying any tricks. As different images in the batch will have a varying amount of predicted objects, we cannot create a tensor with `10` bounding boxes in the first index and `4` in the second.

###### Solution - Padding

To output batched results in this scenario, you can define constant shaped output tensors, and paste results for each image into them. For instance

```py
def forward(self, input):
    # Maximum number of detections the vision model will output per batch
    max_detections = self.model.roi_heads.detections_per_img
    # Variables for output tensor shapes
    # Use tensor.size instead of tensor.shape for dynamic inputs
    batch_size, _, input_height, input_width = input.shape
    # Create batched output tensors
    all_boxes = torch.zeros((batch_size, max_detections, 4))
    all_labels = torch.zeros((batch_size, max_detections))
    all_scores = torch.zeros((batch_size, max_detections))
    # Masks are returned with a redundant channel in the second dimension
    all_masks = torch.zeros((batch_size, max_detections, 1, input_height, input_width))
    # Number of detections per batch
    detections_per_batch = torch.zeros((batch_size, 1))
    # Run forward pass
    outputs = self.model.forward(input)
    for idx, result in enumerate(outputs):
        boxes, labels, scores, masks = result.values()
        # Number of detections for batch
        n_dets = boxes.size(0)
        detections_per_batch[idx] = n_dets
        # Paste batch results into output tensors
        all_boxes[idx, : n_dets] = boxes
        all_labels[idx, : n_dets] = labels
        all_scores[idx, : n_dets] = scores
        all_masks[idx, : n_dets] = masks
    return detections_per_batch, all_boxes, all_labels, all_scores, all_masks
```

This forward pass creates output tensors which can potentially hold
all object detections, and copies the realized object detections for each batch in to them. To keep track of which entries are zero-padding and which are actual detections, a tensor `detections_per_batch` is returned on top of the Mask R-CNN outputs. This is then used to extract the real predictions from ONNX outputs

```py
for preds, boxes, labels, scores, masks in zip(*outputs):
    detected_boxes = boxes[: preds]
    detected_labels = labels[: preds]
    ...
```

###### Considerations

This will have problems with I/O or memory bound applications, as the model always returns outputs with space for all potential detected masks. If you have a good upper bound for the amount of objects, you can limit this by reducing `model.roi_heads.detections_per_img`.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response! But this solution doesn't work as expected. Model output structure changed as requested, but I can't run the model. I export model with x of shape `[1, 3, 512, 512]` and try to run with x of shape `[2, 3, 512, 512]`. ONNX runtime throws following error: `FAIL : Non-zero status code returned while running Split node.`

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. Code above exports the model with static axes, so it has to be run with the batch size defined during export. `torchvision` Mask-RCNN does not support ONNX export with a dynamic batch size - at least not without rewriting a large part of the forward pass.