# How to get dynamic batch size in Onnx model from Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I have a currently working PyTorch to Onnx conversion process that I would like to enable a dynamic batch size for.

I am setting the dynamic axes like this:

```
    model.to_onnx(
        onnx_filepath,
        input_sample=(x, None),
        export_params=True,
        opset_version=17,
        do_constant_folding=True,
        input_names=['image'],
        output_names=['boxes', 'scores', 'labels'],
        dynamic_axes={
            "image": [0],
            "boxes": [0],
            "scores": [0],
            "labels": [0],
        }
    )
```

However, the onnx model that is produced only shows dynamic batch size for the input:

[image: output from netron]

How do I make the output batch size dynamic? Do I need to modify the forward function of the model in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is just a guess](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but are you by any chance processing each input image (or alternatively post-processing detections) of the batch separately inside of a for-loop? If yes, your behaviour might be due to how [torch exports to ONNX](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html#avoid-numpy-and-built-in-python-types), and you will need to modify your forward pass. Or, alternatively you can use `torch.jit.script`.

###### Where forwad pass could go wrong

Check your model for anything that defines a dimension of a tensor that is interpreted as a python integer during export. Setting dynamic axes will try to use variable shapes for the corresponding tensors, but will be overridden by explicit constant ones.

```py
# WRONG - WILL EXPORT WITH STATIC BATCH SIZE
def forward(self, batch):
    bs, c, h, w = batch.shape
    # bs is saved as a constant integer during export
    for i in range(bs):
        do_something()
```

```py
# WRONG - WILL EXPORT WITH STATIC BATCH SIZE
def forward(self, batch):
    # iterating over tensors is not supported for dynamic batch sizes
    # ONNX model will iterate the same amount as in batch during export
    for i in batch:
        do_something()
```

###### Potential fixes

Use `tensor.size` instead of `tensor.shape`

```py
# CORRECT - WILL EXPORT WITH DYNAMIC AXES
def forward(self, batch):
    # This calls a function instead of getting an attribute,
    # the variable will be dynamic
    bs = batch.size(0)
    for i in range(bs):
        do_something()
```

Script parts of the model to preserve control flows and different input sizes

```py
# CORRECT - WILL EXPORT WITH DYNAMIC AXES
# Script parts of the forward pass, e.g. single functions
@torch.jit._script_if_tracing
def do_something(batch):
    for i in batch:
        do_something_else()
    
def forward(self, batch):
    # function will be scripted, dynamic shapes preserved
    do_something(batch)
```

Export the whole module as a `ScriptModule`, preserving all control flows
and input sizes

```py
# CORRECT - WILL EXPORT WITH DYNAMIC AXES
script_module = torch.jit.script(model)
torch.onnx.export(
    script_module,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful info! I am using a torchvision Retinanet model, I tried some of your suggestions, but not having luck with it yet. Do you know if its possible to create a ScriptModule for this kind of model? Or will it need to be custom modified?

Comment: @brad If it is a `torchvision` model then this question is likely a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76928530/customize-pytorch-model-export-to-onnx)

Comment: ok thank you, it sounds like if I want a batch size larger than one I should switch away from torchvision